# Azure AD B2C password rest not working in Sign in v2 flow

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

The temporary password from the Azure portal when you manually reset a user password does not seem to work on the "Sign in v2" user flow, it does, however, work on the "Sign in" user flow.
I assume this is a bug since the v2 flow is still in preview.
Both user flows are under the same domain.
Is this a known issue? I was not able to find any information in the fast-developing Azure world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password reset through Azure Portal against a B2C Local Account is not supported for any flow, except the old Sign In flow. This is referred to as ForceChangePassword.